# How to get the folder name in InMemoryUploadedFile in django?

Tags: python, django, tar, in-memory-database

In the django project I was working on, the uploaded tar file is stored as an `InMemoryUploadedFile`. I want to know the name of folder obtained by extracting that tar file. How can I do that?

For example, a folder named "abcd" is created and it is compressed. We get "abcd.tar.gz". Now it's name is changed to "addition.tar.gz". I have uploaded this "addition.tar.gz". It is stored as an `InMemoryUploadedFile`.How can I get the name of folder *i.e.* "abcd" which is inside the uploaded tar.gz file?
[image: Click to view image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the proper way but i have applied a jugaad to solve it ;). May be it will help you.

```
variable = request.FILES["your_data"].name
variable = variable.replace('.tar.gz','')
print(variable)
```